# Application crashes when debugging over jtag

Tags: eclipse, intel-fpga, jtag, nios, ucos

I'm having an issue when attempting to analyze variables in the Eclipse IDE, while in debug mode. At a breakpoint, I'll try to expand a data structure, in the Eclipse variables window, however, the member doesn't display and the program running on the board seems to crash. Once this happens, the only way to reconnect over the jtag is to reboot the board and restart Eclipse.

Without knowing for certain, it seems to be an error with memory allocation in the IDE, but I don't know. Is this a common problem when debugging over jtag? Where might I begin looking to resolve the issue?

Comment: Does it display a specific error code or stacktrace when the program crashes? I'd google a specific stacktrace or error message and go from there if you can. Is the problem the same if you simulate instead of running as hardware? Can you include a stracktrace? Which versions of the Altera software is it? I got a working environment with altera de2 + ubuntu + quartus II + µC/OS running in Oracle Virtual Box that needed some spec versions and adjustments.

Comment: @909Niklas thank you for the comment. The application is running on the Nios II soft processor. Version are 12.1sp1 for both Nios II and Quartus II. I'll see if I can provide more detail in a stack trace.